# Excel VBA overlapping error for deleting highlighted rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to understand why this error pops up when it didn't before

```
Sub deleterow()
   Dim cell As Range, DelRange As Range

   For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:G2000")
       If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
           If DelRange Is Nothing Then
               Set DelRange = cell
           Else
               Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, cell)
           End If
       End If
    Next cell

   If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.EntireRow.Delete ' error here
End Sub
```

This is part of a recorded VBA macro for deleting highlighted rows but it's showing an error Run time error "1004" - "cannot use that command on overlapping selection" in the line DelRange.EntireRow.Delete.

It didn't occur before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are getting this error, because in some of the rows you are having 2 cells with a **Yellow** Interior, so you are adding 2 cells in the same row to your `DelRange`, and then try to delete the same row twice. i.e. let's say that both "C3" and "G3" are yellow, you add them both to `DelRange`, and the when you try to delete `DelRange.EntireRow.Delete`, you are trying to delete row 3 twice - thus resulting with the Run-Time error.

Comment: i figured out the issue was with one of the columns with non highlighting, it was suppose to run in such a way as the highlighted rows may be one after the other. thanks for replying :)

Comment: one after another will work, but with your code, you can't have 2 cells in the same row. Unless you change your code's concept a little

Comment: could you explain further? i don't quite understand what you mean by 2 cells in the same row. I believe i was capturing the rows within the whole range ("A2:F2000") and finding the highlighted ones to delete

Comment: my apologies YowE3K

Comment: That's OK - we all learn the rules of the site bit by bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub deleterow()
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:G2000")
    With cell
        If .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then .EntireRow.Delete
    End With
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```